# iOS 13 continuous background locations update

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, ios13

I have a question on iOS continuous background locations update, that I use for an app that tracks the trips in the car. Before iOS 13, we haven't problems whit the update in the background. From iOS 13, in particular(but I'm not sure) with iOS 13.3, I noticed two things:

- seems that the locations arrive every x meters. Until iOS 13 the locations seems to arrive every second. The distance filter is set in this way: `locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone`.
- before iOS 13, the app ran in the background forever. Now, it seems that after a period of not moving, the system delivers far fewer locations.

My locations manager is made in this way:

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
locationManager.activityType = .other
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```

Suggestion?

Comment: If this is for tracking in a car, why are you lying to the location manager about it? Your values should describe honestly what you are doing: `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`,  `.automotiveNavigation`. Or if I've misunderstood what you mean by "tracks the trips in car", please explain more clearly what your goal is.

Comment: I need that gps polling is not stopped. The way is .other. In every case, can this influence in some way the delivering of locations?

Comment: The way to prevent gps polling from being stopped is `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`, as I said. That's because it tells the location manager that the device will be powered externally so there is no need to save battery.

Comment: mmm...```kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation``` give me a location with the max level of horizontal accuracy. I use this option only if iPhone is in charge. In every case, this not resolve my problem. I use my framework from iOS 10 and I never had problems

Comment: iOS has grown much more strict about backgrounding rules in iOS 13. The fact that something worked previously does not mean it was supported or can be reproduced precisely in iOS 13.

Comment: You have specified `.kCLLocationAccuracyBest`, os you have already incurred the battery penalty of running the GPS.

Comment: Penalty? I don’t understand

Comment: @nunziogiuliocaggegi did you find the solution for it?

Comment: I'm not sure. in the last few days it seems to be going. it was probably a bug in my app. do you also have the same problem?